# Pokemon Stat Calculation With IVs

Tags: javascript

Im working on a site that allows you to create your own pokemon by inputing stats and level.

I had it working without calculating IVs (Individual value is a variable stat on all pokemon that affects their growth).

This is the initial function I had that worked just fine

```
function hpStat(pokemonLevel) {
"use strict";
var baseHP = document.getElementById("baseHP").value;

var hp = Math.floor(((baseHP * 2) * (pokemonLevel / 100)) + 10 + pokemonLevel);
return hp; }
```

But when I tried adding the IV calculation it gives me ridiculously high numbers. I tried adjusting the order of operations but I always get a massive number. I can find my error.
New function:

```
function hpStat(pokemonLevel) {
"use strict";
var baseHP = document.getElementById("baseHP").value;
var hpIV = document.getElementById("hpIV").value;

var hp = Math.floor((((hpIV + baseHP) * 2) * (pokemonLevel / 100)) + 10 + pokemonLevel);
return hp; }
```

The "hpIV" element is an input tag that has a range of 0-31.

Comment: Hmm. If `hpIV` is a string (as I suspect), then `(hpIV + baseHP) * 2` is going to concat those values, then multiply by two. Eg: `("9" + 7) * 2` will be 97*2. Try converting those two values to numbers explicitly first: `(Number(hpIV) + Number(baseHP)) * 2`

Comment: ^^^ what @CRice said.

Comment: @CRice: That should be an answer rather than a comment. Comment votes don't earn rep.

Comment: @KenWhite I suppose you're right. I didn't want to post it since I wasn't sure that was the actual problem with OPs code (it was a guess), but it seems pretty likely. I'll go ahead and post an answer for it.

Comment: awesome fixed everything. thanks for the help, still pretty new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `.value` property of an input element returns that value **as a string**. Then, if you try to use strings for numerical calculations unknowingly, weird things happen. An example:

```
"1" + 1;
// Returns "11" <- string

1 + 1
// Returns 2 <- number
```

So your code for adding the IV and base HP are using strings, which instead of adding numerically, will concatenate the strings instead. Then when you multiply by two, it's automatically casted back to number again, leading to your odd result. To fix it, just make sure your values are numbers from the get go:

```
// Note that we now wrap these in a Number() call to cast them.
var baseHP = Number(document.getElementById("baseHP").value);
var hpIV = Number(document.getElementById("hpIV").value);
```

From there your code *should* work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your values as integers.  They're operating as strings.